# Spring hateoas jaxrslinkbuilder adds null fields

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jax-rs

I am trying to add HATEOAS links to my Controller results.
Link creation:

```
       Link link = JaxRsLinkBuilder.linkTo(MainRestService.class)
                    .slash(this::getVersion)
                    .slash(LinkMappingConstants.TAXPAYERS)
                    .slash(taxPayerId)
                    .slash(LinkMappingConstants.ESTIMATIONS)
                    .slash(estimationId)
                    .withSelfRel();
```

The link itself is created fine, but there are superfluous entries in the resulting JSON:

```
"links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/blablabla",
          "hreflang": null,
          "media": null,
          "title": null,
          "type": null,
          "deprecation": null,
          "template": {
            "variables": [

            ],
            "variableNames": [

            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

How can i get this format? (without use property `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL`)

```
"links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/blablabla"
        }
      ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, if you want `NON_NULL` property inclusion on the whole JSON and not just `links` you can use `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL`. This won't fix the empty template fields however.

If you want to have `NON_NULL` property inclusion on just the `Link` object using Jackson for serialization you can achieve this by using a [Jackson MixIn](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) for the `Link` object with the `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` annotation.

As an example:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
abstract class LinkMixIn {
}
```

```
mapper.addMixIn(Link.class, LinkMixIn.class);
```

To hide the template fields you can either add @JsonIgnore if you never want the template section to be serialized, or try `NON_DEFAULT` property inclusion on the above answer which creates a new instance of the object and compares it to what is to be serialized to determine if it should be included.

E.g. something like the following would not serialize the result of getTemplate at all

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
abstract class LinkMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore abstract Template getTemplate();
}
```

Comment: Anyway with this property field "template" will remain.

Comment: @kros365 That's true - additional MixIn customisation would be required for that (either NON_DEFAULT or ignore), I'll update my answer to reflect it.

Comment: I use org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport and JaxRsLinkBuilder for creation link. Not a problem create custom link, just I thought that there is a way to configure this solution.

Comment: @kros365 the answer above should cover customisation of the serialization to be what you requested, either by using `JsonIgnore` to ignore properties completely, or only hiding them when they are null. Let me know if something is not clear.